# How to connect ejabberd with phpmyadmin for storing messages into database?

Tags: ejabberd

I downloaded the XAMPP server which has Apache and MySQL in it. link: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

I downloaded the 20.01 version of the ejabberd installer for windows 10 OS. After that, I run the installer and installed the ejabberd in my Program files folder.

I created the ejabberd database in http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php and imported all the tables from mysql.sql file using C:\Program Files\ejabberd-20.01\lib\ejabberd-20.01\priv\sql folder.
Database setup completed. After that,
I configured the ejabberd.yml file.

After that, I installed the Pidgin Client for a chat then I started the ejabberd node.
According to the below ejabberd.yml configuration, The ejabberd node is running fine and I am able to chat with users in the Pidgin client.

I registered a new user in the ejabberd dashboard But I am not getting the message data and registered user data (username and password) into the PHPMyAdmin MySQL database.

My purpose for this issue is to use the ejabberd MySQL database which is already created by me in PHPMyAdmin. I want to store chat messages in the ejabberd MySQL database.
ejabberd.yml file:

```
hosts:
  - "localhost"

loglevel: 4
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1
log_rate_limit: 100

certfiles:
  - "C:/ProgramData/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
##  - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem"
##  - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/privkey.pem"

ca_file: "C:/ProgramData/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5269
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  -
    port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
  -
    port: 1883
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@localhost"
sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "root"
sql_password: ""
access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          acl: loopback
          acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            acl: loopback
            acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:admin@localhost"
   ca_url: "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org"

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: never
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      mam: false
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false

### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8
```

Answer (score 0):

> I registered a new user in the ejabberd dashboard But I am not getting the message data and registered user data (username and password) into the PHPMyAdmin MySQL database.

If you login in ejabberd WebAdmin with an admin account, and go to -> Nodes -> your node -> Database, you will see that the internal Mnesia table "passwd" has 1 Element. That means one account is registered in ejabberd, and stored in the Mnesia database. That's the internal database used by default.

> ejabberd.yml file:
>
> ```
> sql_type: mysql
> sql_server: "localhost"
> sql_database: "ejabberd"
> sql_username: "root"
> sql_password: ""
> ```

Ok, those options tell ejabberd what SQL database you want to use, and how to connect to it.

> I want to store chat messages in the ejabberd MySQL database.

Then, tell ejabberd to use sql for the tasks that you want. For example, add also those options to your config:

```
auth_method: sql
default_db: sql
```

See:
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/toplevel/#auth-method
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/toplevel/#default-db

Comment: My connection is working fine. Now, I am getting usernames and passwords in my Mysql database. I have done all the above configurations in the ejabberd.yml file. I created the two users in Pidgin. But still, I am not getting chat message data in the table of database. Please help.

Comment: This "chat message data" is stored somewhere else, or nowhere at all?

Comment: I'm getting messages, I just changed the mod_mam db_type to SQL and default to always.